# Animate a template in Meteor

Tags: javascript, animation, meteor

There's a good [library](https://github.com/webtempest/meteor-animate) but I could use it to transition lists only. (I might be doing wrong ?)

However, I wanted to flip a counter whenever it was incremented. The solution I came with looks really ugly to me. I went from :

```
//counter.js
Template.counter.helpers({
    counter: function () {
        return Counts.get('counter');
    }
});

//counter.html
<template name="counter">
    <div class="ui clearing counterBlock">
        <h1 class="ui header centered">Contacts</h1>
        <h2 class="counter ui header centered">{{ counter }}</h2>
    </div>
</template>
```

for the non animated version to

```
//counter.js
var prevCounter = 0, counterTpl;

Template.counterBlock.onRendered(function () {
    counterTpl = Blaze.render(Template.counter, $(".counter")[0]);
});

Template.counter.helpers({
    counter: function () {
        var c = Counts.get('counter');

        if (c != prevCounter) {
            $(".counter .animated").removeClass('flipInX').addClass('flipOutX');
            Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
                prevCounter = c;
                Blaze.remove(counterTpl);
                counterTpl = Blaze.render(Template.counter, $(".counter")[0]);
            }, 1000);
        }

        return prevCounter;
    }
});

//counter.html
<template name="counterBlock">
    <div class="ui clearing counterBlock">
        <h1 class="ui header centered">Contacts</h1>
        <h2 class="counter ui header centered">
        </h2>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="counter">
    <span class="animated flipInX">{{counter}}</span>
</template>
```

I'm quite new to meteor universe but I'm still wondering if there's any proper way to animate a simple reactive change

Answer (score 2):

Meteor do provided `_uihook` to animate DOM element which is removed or added

Theres are examples you can find on [Github](https://github.com/search?p=1&q=_uihooks&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Following are another example which enabled the **fade-in/out** animation when elements are added or removed from `domElement`

```
domElement._uihooks = {
    insertElement: function(node, next) {
      $(node)
        .hide()
        .insertBefore(next)
        .fadeIn();
    },
    removeElement: function(node) {
      $(node).fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: uihooks works great for list where there is DOM manipulation. Here, I just want to animate the update of a value in my template.

If I'm wrong, can you provide a working sample ?